# Is there a transport equation specially for two rotating frames?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics

The classical transport equations related vector derivatives between an inertial frame and a rotating frame, is this equation applicable to a set of frames where both are rotating? or does one always have to be inertial?

Answer (score 0):

Transport from Rotating 1 to Inertial, and then from Inertial to Rotating 2.